# Copy value of one column into another column in edit form

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, edit-form, multiline-text-field

I want to copy value of multi line of text column to another multi line of text column in edit form.

I need this because first column has feature append to save and display previous entries, but as you know with append activated when user enters some text and saves item that text won't show in edit form when user opens item again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    // instead of TDs' IDs I put autogenereted IDs of DIVs and solved this.
    $("#ctl00_ctl40_g_82eb9f08_066e_4bbc_a801_f88a93c73177_ff21_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte").text($("#ctl00_ctl40_g_82eb9f08_066e_4bbc_a801_f88a93c73177_ff31_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte").text());
});
```